# session management across tabs in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2, session-variables

Technology-- Struts2 & JSP

1. Access URL--http://localhost:8080/session_acroos_tab/login.action
2. In Welcome.jsp user is entering some value in 'First Text Field' and clicks on 'First button'.
3. On clicking this button(First button),firstButtonClick function of `LoginAction.java` is called.
4. Now control will again transfer to `Welcome.jsp`. On this jsp value entered by user in 'First Text Field' is displayed,
5. User shall enter some value in 'Second Text Field' and clicks on 'Second button'.
6. On clicking this button(Second button),secondButtonClick function of `LoginAction.java` is called, and control shall again go to `Welcome.jsp` page.

Before executing step 5th, if user open new tab and execute from step 1 to 3 and again come back to tab-1 and execute remaining steps than all session data got mess-up. I know, all the opened new tabs shall share the same session but than what is the solution. I want to work both tabs independently.

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<head> 
<title>Welcome</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickSecondButton(form)
{
    form.action="secondButtonClickForm2";
    form.submit(); 
}
</script>
</head>
<s:form action="firstButtonClickForm2" method="post">
    <s:if test="%{#session.HIDE_FIRST_BUTTON!=null}">
        <ul>
            <li>FIRST TEXT FIELD VALUE - <s:property value="%{#session.FIRST_TEXT_FIELD}"/></li>
        </ul>
        <s:textfield name="secondtextfield" key="label.secondtextfield" size="20"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit key="label.secondButton" align="center" onclick="clickSecondButton(this.form)"></s:submit>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <s:textfield name="firsttextfield" key="label.fisttextfield" size="20"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit key="label.firstButton" align="center"></s:submit>
    </s:else>
</s:form>
```

**LoginAction.java**

```
package net.patel.struts2;
import java.util.Map;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;

public class LoginAction {
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String firsttextfield;
  private String secondtextfield;    

  public String execute() {
    Map session = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    session.clear();
    if (this.username==null)
        return "success";

    if (this.username.equals("admin") 
            && this.password.equals("admin123")) {
        return "success";
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
  }

  public String firstButtonClick() {
  System.out.println("{firstButtonClick} "+firsttextfield);
  Map session = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
  session.put("HIDE_FIRST_BUTTON", "Y");
  //session.put("FIRST_TEXT_FIELD", firsttextfield);
  return "success";
  }

  public String secondButtonClick() {
  Map session = (Map) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
  System.out.println("{secondButtonClick} firsttextfield-"+session.get("FIRST_TEXT_FIELD")+" II TF-"+secondtextfield);

  return "success";
  }

  public String getUsername() {
      return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getFirsttextfield() {
    return firsttextfield;
  }

  public void setFirsttextfield(String firsttextfield) {
    this.firsttextfield = firsttextfield;
  }

  public String getSecondtextfield() {
    return secondtextfield;
  }

  public void setSecondtextfield(String secondtextfield) {
    this.secondtextfield = secondtextfield;
  }

}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"></constant>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="login" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
    </action>    
    <action name="*Form2" class="net.viralpatel.struts2.LoginAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
    </action>    
    </package>
  </struts>
```

**ApplicationResources.properties**

```
 label.username= Username
 label.password= Password
 label.login= Login 
 label.fisttextfield=First Text Field
 label.firstButton=First Button
 label.secondtextfield=Second Text Field
 label.secondButton=Second Button
```

Try to be more clear, i'm in lack of ideas in this problem, even it sounds like a classic :I have spend hours trying to play around with this but have got nowhere.Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use some token to *identify* a tab.

Comment: Before welcome page create some token and pass it along. When second tab is opened token will be different than the first tab one and you can show values according to token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always need a token. It can be generated and maintained both  `server-side` (Java) and `client-side` ([HTML5 **sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)).

Then it can be used to pin a certain page/tab to a certain set of session attributes, by parameterizing them.

An example of the server-side way is to generate the token in a BaseAction extended by all the others. It would be better to do it in an Interceptor, but that's up to you.

In this case, **since it's not a security token** (eg. a token to counter XSRF, that needs to be not predictable), you can use the current time as a token.

E.g. of server side token:

```
public abstract class BaseAction extends ActionSupport 
                                  implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String,Object>  session;       
    private String token;

    public void setSession(Map<String,Object> session) {
        this.session = session;
    }
    public void setToken(String token) {
        // Retrieve the Token from the page, if any
        this.token = token;
    }
    public String getToken() {
        if (token==null){
            // Generates a new Token, only if it has not been passed from the JSP
            token = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }       
        return token;
    }
    public void setTokenSessionAttribute(String k, Object v){
        session.putSessionAttribute(getToken() + "_" + k,v);
    }
    public Object getTokenSessionAttribute(String k){
        return session.getSessionAttribute(getToken() + "_" + k);
    }


    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String firstButtonClick() {
        setTokenSessionAttribute("FIRST_TEXT_FIELD", firstTextField);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String secondButtonClick() {
        log.debug("Saved value was: " + getTokenSessionAttribute("FIRST_TEXT_FIELD"))
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    private String firstTextField; // with setter

}
```

in your JSPs:

```xml
<s:form ... >
    <!-- stuff -->
    <s:hidden name="token" />
    <!-- stuff -->
    <s:if test="%{#session[token+'HIDE_FIRST_BUTTON']!=null}">
        <!-- stuff -->
    <!-- stuff -->
</s:form>
```

This is one among many ways, for example you could create a method in the action returning the right, parameterized session attribute:

```java
public Object getTabSessionObj(String k){
    return session.get(token + "_" + k);
}
```

```xml
<s:if test="%{getTabSessionObj('HIDE_FIRST_BUTTON')!=null}">
```

Comment: ...Thanx for reply! Now session-key has been changed dynamically,New new session key is HIDE_FIRST_BUTTON+$systemCurrentTime. How will i access it in JSP through OGNL expr? Now code(<s:if test="%{#session.HIDE_FIRST_BUTTON!=null}">) shall be changed.

Comment: I've added it to the answer

Comment: Why ? Not for a security token of course, but this is just a token to make multiple tabs work. Sessions are unique per user, so concurrent users won't be a problem. The only problem would be a user opening two tabs at the same time and ending in the same line of two actions executions in the same millisecond. And even in that 1^2337 case, the only result would be one tab not working, and needing an F5

Comment: End users a very... skillful in hitting exact this 1^2337 case. ;) And not so experienced devs upon seeing timestamp as token think "ah cool lets use it all the time...". As I've said it is just a note. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM I've edited to prevent this, before you commented :D I don't want to make the wrong message pass :)

Comment: And lol at 1^2337 that is always 1 ahahahahahaha I've noticed it now re-reading, it obviously was 2^1337 in my mind @AleksandrM :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML5 SessionStorage (window.sessionStorage). You will generate a random id and save in session Storage per Browser Tab. Then each browser tab has his own Id.

"Data stored using sessionStorage do not persist across browser tabs, even if two tabs both contain webpages from the same domain origin. In other words, data inside sessionStorage is confined to not just the domain and directory of the invoking page, but the browser tab in which the page is contained in. Contrast that to session cookies, which do persist data from tab to tab."